# Twilio programable Voice conference

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I have an app having sever-side code on node js(express) and front-end on react js. Now I have an array of numbers on client-side I want to make a conference call taking all passed numbers as participants But I can't figured out any flow for it.

I have seen the way of generating the conference through API but how I will take microphone access from front-end and all that access required to make a call from device if I only use twilio API. For this reason I want to mix it with Devise sdk so that I can make calls from browser. But when I call connect method from front-end it is generating conference. But how can I add participants into that conference from client-side devise object.